# Loop over dataframe, groupby and save transformed values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stuck.

I have a Pandas DataFrame with 2 groups and 3 columns.  like this:

```
Group  Var_A  Var_B  Var_C
1       4.5    5.6    8.6
1       3.2    6.7    7.5
2       2.1    6.5    2.3
2       3.2    4.5    3.4
...     ...    ...    ...
```

I'm trying to iterate over the groups and columns to apply a transformation (i.e. BoxCox transformation) to the values, then save the modified values as new variables at the end of the dataframe.

I can't seem to get it to work right.

I get as far as what is shown below, but then I don't know how to append the new values, since it is going Group-wise over the data, then column by column.

```
def modify(df):
    df = df.sort_values('Group')
    temp = df.groupby('Group')

    for name, group in temp:
        for col in group[['Var_A', 'Var_B', 'Var_C']]:
        z = stats.boxcox(group[col]) # this is an array
    ...not sure what comes next...
```

(now I need to add the transformed array (z) for Var_A, Var_B and Var_C, for each group, back to the original DataFrame --> df... in the same order to keep everything straight.).  I'm sure this has to be quite rudimentary.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: this transform function, can you given add the exact inputs and the output to this function? maybe give a dummy function?

Comment: There should be 3 new columns added to the  data frame, like var_a_transform, var_b_transform, etc.  The transformation needs to apply to the variable (Var_a, for example) within each group:. 1, 2, 3...n

Comment: yea i get that, but its not clear what the transform function does currently. Please add a dummy transform function for reference. (primarily inputs and output datatypes for the transform function)

Comment: Lets make it easy.  The transform function returns the square root of each value in the column.  So it take, as input, an array of values.  Like a single column from a data frame.

Comment: great, please add that to the question as well! please read [how to add minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in SO

Comment: Do try to understand, the problem you are trying to solve is HIGHLY dependent on the function you are using. the input and output data types, and how the function processes the column/dataframe is critical to coming up with the solution. Its important you specify it exactly, so as to ensure that the solutions provided to you are actually solving your core problem. Please understand that adding the end-to-end example allows you to define the scope of the question as well.

Comment: For the example you have given above in your comments - `df.set_index('Group').groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x**2)` would work. However, I do know that it wont work with the complex case you are mentioning. So its important that you add the required details around the function so that other can properly assist.

Comment: Modified to be more clear. Goal: loop over each group, then loop over a subset of columns by name, transform the values in the column, and add back to the data frame.